# Where do I put my code to pre-fill a form build using flutter_form_builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-form-builder

I'm building a form using flutter_form_builder on flutter and I need to pre-fill the form from a local database when the form is opened for the second time. When I call this in the `initState` it fails to pre-fill the form widgets.

```dart
setState(() {
   _formKey.currentState!.patchValue({
       'subCity': result?.subCity,
       'landmark': result?.landmark,
   });
});
```

I've looked at the documentation for flutter_form_builder and there is no mention of the lifecycle I need to use to perform this action. It only shows how to handle submitting the form.

If anybody has experienced this please let me know how you have solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a TextEditingController to each field, then initialize each on initState, here is an example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _formController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  
  void initState() {
    _formController.value = TextEditingValue(text: 'initializedValue');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: Center(
        child: FormBuilder(
          child: FormBuilderTextField(
            name: 'the text field',
            controller: _formController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't  there a simpler option for patching values on forms other that using the controller. because defining controller for all my values is not a reusable and easy approach.

Comment: Yeah, that's a big headache I have for 3 years now, let me know if you find an easier solution.

Comment: I think we can contribute to flutter_form_builder to create the controller internally and set the value in the patch method. Did you look in to this kind of solution?

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find any and yeah contributing would be great.

Comment: Ok. I’ll see what I can do and post the PR here to get everybody approaching it and solving it once and for all.